# The static method newBoard(int) from the type Board should be accessed in a static way. Java Lines of Action Game

Tags: java

The program will run in the command line in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04).
The Board class was partially coded for us.

```
public class Loa{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int boardSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Board playBoard = new Board();


    playBoard.newBoard(boardSize);//atom gives a warning on this line. about static method
  }
}
```

Board class:

```
/*
 * This class implements the board. It stores an array that contains the content
 * of the board, and several functions that perform operations such as moving a
 * piece or counting the number of markers in a row, column, or diagonal.
 */
public class Board {

    // The size of the board
    private static int size;

    // The pieces
    public static final int INVALID = -1;
    public static final int EMPTY = 0;
    public static final int WHITE = 1;
    public static final int BLACK = 2;

    // The board
    private static int[][] board;
    // Convention: board[0][0] is the southwest square

    /*
     * Create and set up a new board
     */
    public static void newBoard(int newSize) {
        /*--------------------------------------------
         * FILL IN THE CODE FOR INITIALIZING THE BOARD
         *-------------------------------------------*/
         if (newSize > 16 || newSize < 4) {
            System.out.println("Error, invalid size.  Please enter a size from 4 - 16.");
        }else {
            size = newSize;
            board = new int[newSize][newSize];
        }

    }
```

I do not know how to initialize the board like in the first code block in LOA class.  I want to make the board eg. 5.  So I would put in the command line `~$ java Loa 5`  But I do not know what it means that it should be accessed in a static way.

The reason I am using Atom for java is that the University doesn't want us to use an IDE yet.  I don't know why.

```
The static method newBoard(int) from the type Board should be accessed in a static way
```

This is the warning/error that atom throws up.  I am confused as I haven't seen this warning yet in my little bit of coding experience.

There is more code available but not necessary for me to understand the Static warning method.

Comment: Did you just ask this same (now closed) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611160/how-do-i-program-a-board-in-lines-of-action)?

Comment: This method, `playBoard.newBoard(boardSize);` is better called `Board.newBoard(boardSize);` since it's a static method. You're better to  call it on the class, not on the instance since `newBoard(...)` is a static method, a method of the class.

Comment: You're probably in the same class as the other questioner

Comment: I am in the same class as the other questioner.  My question was about the static method.  But I see that there is another post about it.  I did not post the other question.

Comment: Board.newBoard(boardSize); worked, sorry about the duplicate question.